# How to provision file to SharePoint document library?

Tags: provisioning, module

We have added a VS module and foll. is the elements.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Module1" Url="Shared Documents" RootWebOnly="True" Path="Module1" >
    <File Url="Sample.txt" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Since RootWebOnly=true, the file gets deployed only to the RootWeb. Now, if we remove this, then, still the file gets deployed only to root web.

1. How to deploy this to all webs in the sitecollection?
2. If we set url to `http://serverurl:port/subsite` and set RootWebOnly="True", then the file is not deployed anywhere. If we set set RootWebOnly="False", then also the file is not deployed any where.
3. If we set url to `http://serverurl:port/` and set RootWebOnly="True" or "False", then the file is deployed to root web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules with `RootWebOnly="TRUE"` will only deploy the files to the `Rootweb` of the Site Collection and it requires that the feature is `Site` scoped.

If you try to deploy a module with the `RootWebOnly="TRUE"` property to a **Web** then it won't work as SharePoint expects the target to be of `SPSite` and not `SPWeb`.

Thus your attempt to deploy the file to url `http://serverurl:port/subsite` will not work, unless you remove the `RootWebOnly` property and make the feature `Web` scoped (though I think the scope won't matter in this case, but for good order's sake make it `Web` scoped).

So to answer your question **How to deploy this to all webs in the sitecollection?**:

- Set the feature deploying the module to `Web` scoped.
- Remove the `RootWebOnly` property from the `<Module />` or set it to `FALSE`.
- Make sure that all webs in the site collection have a document library named "Shared Documents".

Comment: 1. What about the siteURL, does it matter whether it is root site or subsite? Also, 2. Is the SiteURL VS deployment specific and independent of the powershell deployment?

Comment: @variable Yes the site url matters. Set the site url for deployment to be your site collection url `http://serverurl:port/`. When the feature then gets deployed, if it `Web` scoped all sites (webs) in the site collection will be affected.

Comment: I also notice that when I follow your method, then, for every subsite I have to manually activate the feature. Is there a way to make this automatic? Also please answer my Q2 in comment1

Comment: @variable To answer your Q2: Yes it is deployment specific and independent of powershell deployment. To active the feature on all webs you can make a powershell script that loops through all webs in the site collection and activate the feature. Another approach, which only works when deploying through VS, is to open your solutions properties, go to the **SharePoint** tab and in the dropdown **Active Deployment Configuration** select **Default**.